# How to integrate Pikachoose jquery gallery with Colorbox?

Tags: jquery

I've tried a couple of things but nothing worked.

This enables the colorbox only for the main image being shown:

```
$("#pikame").PikaChoose({carousel:true});
$(".pika-stage a").colorbox({rel:'colorbox'});
```

This is how they recommend to integrate fancybox (not colorbox, which I want):

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   var a = function(self){
      self.anchor.fancybox();
   };
   $("#pikame").PikaChoose({buildFinished:a});
});
```